# CMake and including other makefiles

Tags: build-process, include, makefile, cmake

Lets say I have a CMakeLists.txt and I want to call another include another makefile in that file (similar to the #include syntax in C), how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3ainclude):

- **`include`**: Read CMake listfile code from the given file.

  ```
  include(<file|module> [OPTIONAL] [RESULT_VARIABLE <VAR>]
                      [NO_POLICY_SCOPE])
  ```

Example use:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include (Project.txt)
```

Project.txt:

```
project (Project)
add_executable(Project project.c)
```